# ARR is striping of Authentication Type: x509 header when used as a Load Balancer

Tags: authentication, iis, load-balancer

I am using ARR as a Load Balancer between my API Server and API Clients. My API Clients use CMS Authentication for communicating with the API Server. When I introduce ARR in between by API Client and API Server, I could see that Authentication Type: is blank whereas when I connect directly I see Authentication Type: x509.

I would like to know If I have to configure IIS or ARR to allow the CMS type of Authentication.